# Asyncronous Database Calls in Flask and Jinja2

Tags: python, mysql, flask

My app reads information from a 3rd party API and my database, then returns a rendered template with the data.

My database (MySQL) is slow and I think that Flask is only rendering my page after the database call is complete.  Is there any way to make this asynchronous?  Or is there a way to make the database calls individually when a user clicks on a page in my app?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot render the template before you have the data needed to render the template.  Consider optimizing your queries.  Assuming you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can use [Flask-Debugtoolbar](http://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to examine how many queries are being run when rendering a template.

Typically database access is reasonably fast.  What is likely happening (although you've shown no code to confirm this) is that you are incurring extra queries while accessing relationships.  If you are rendering a list of instances, and accessing a relation ship on each instance, this will be 1 query for the instances + one query to load the relationship for each instance.  Consider using [eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_relationships.html) to pre-load the relationships in a single query.